# Cloud Function failing to access Firebase Database

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

So I am trying to very simply read and update data from my Firebase Database, and it is giving me an error.

"Error: Could not handle request"

I followed the instructions to initialize my app from Google's [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started)
I deploy my methods as suggested `firebase deploy --only functions`
And I get the following response:

```
i  deploying functions
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
✔  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (63.07 KB) for uploading
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: current functions in project: addMessage, helloWorld, now, weather, weather2
i  functions: uploading functions in project: weather
i  functions: updating function weather...
✔  functions[weather]: Successful update operation.
Function URL (weather): https://us-central1-*****.cloudfunctions.net/weather
```

Interestingly, their example method "addMessage" works fine:

```
// Take the text parameter passed to this HTTP endpoint and insert it into the
// Realtime Database under the path /messages/:pushId/original
exports.addMessage = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  // Grab the text parameter.
  const original = req.query.text;
  // Push the new message into the Realtime Database using the Firebase Admin SDK.
  admin.database().ref('/messages').push({original: original}).then(snapshot => {
    // Redirect with 303 SEE OTHER to the URL of the pushed object in the Firebase console.
    res.redirect(303, snapshot.ref);
  });
});
```

However, when I try to make my own method using this [tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#updating_or_deleting_data) on updating data instead of pushing data, I run into problems Any help on this is greatly appreciated, I have been working at this for hours.

how my data is structured:

-
My code:

```
exports.weather = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  admin.database.ref('/weather').once('value').then(snapshot => {
    var temp = snapshot.child('temp').val();
    var time = snapshot.child("time").val()
    var diff = diff_minutes(Date().getTime(), time)
    //If the last request >=5 minutes, call DarkSky API & Update database
    if (diff >= 5) {
       var updates = {
          time: NEW_TIME,
          temp: NEW_TEMPERATURE
        }
        snapshot.update(updates)
        response.send(updates);
    }
     else {
      response.send(temp)
    }
  })
});

function diff_minutes(second_time, first_time) {
  var diff =(second_time - first_time) / (1000 * 60);
  return Math.abs(Math.round(diff));
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If you're new to both the Dark Sky API and Cloud Functions, I'd recommend first trying to invoke Dark Sky from a regular node script. It reduces the number of things that could cause the problem.

Comment: The Dark Sky API works fine by itself, to be honest, it could be removed from the entire thing - if I just wanted to return the data from the Firebase Database, it would be an error

Comment: I am going to remove Dark Sky API from the question since you are right, it is irrelevant.

Comment: In that case: please create a separate [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including how you call the function. As it stands now, I have no idea where the error occurs.

Comment: I see. I recreated this question from scratch as it limits me to 1 question per 90minutes. But from my research I don't see how my code would produce an error either.

Comment: You can edit this question. If the calling of Dark Sky is not needed to reproduce the problem, it shouldn't be in a minimal repro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code to update the database and send the response is not correct:

```
snapshot.update(updates);
response.send(updates);
```

`snapshot` is an instance of [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot) and does not have an `update()` method.

Replace those two statements with:

```
snapshot.ref.update(updates).then(() => {
  response.send(updates);
}).catch(error => {
    console.error('Update failed:', error);
    response.send('Update failed'); // or some error status of your choice
});
```

Also:

Change `admin.database.ref` to `admin.database().ref`

Change `Date().getTime()` to `Date.now()`

Comment: I thought that would definitely fix it but still no luck! Could it be a problem with firebase? Is there a way to reset the system? I get `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()`

Comment: still doesn't work! This is REALLY annoying, the error must be somewhere here   `admin.database.ref('/weather').once('value').then(snapshot => {`

Comment: If you're doing so already, look at the Cloud Function logs at the Firebase Console.  They contain run info and error messages.  Add `console.log()` statements to log debug info.  I was able to run your code after making the changes I noted.

Comment: For safety, your code should include a check of `snapshot.exists()` to confirm that the DB contains a value at `/weather`

Comment: You are actually a hero. I don't really know exactly what I did after reading your comments, but it was something along the lines of smashing my keyboard a few times and saying a hail mary and then it worked.

Comment: "Change admin.database.ref to admin.database().ref" you saved me!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final code with Dark Sky's API and all (thank you to everyone who helped!):

This code, on HTTP request, checks the time of the last API call to Dark Sky API's request for a specific location, then uses the previous results if within the last 5minutes, or updates the results if longer.

[image: data]

```
exports.weather = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  admin.database().ref('/weather').once('value').then(snapshot => {
      var temp = snapshot.child('temp').val();
      var time = snapshot.child("time").val();
      var diff = diff_minutes(Date.now(), time);
      var current = {
        time: time,
        temp: temp
      }
      if (diff >= 5) {
        DarkSkyApi.loadCurrent(position).then(result => {
          var updates = {
            time: result.time,
            temp: result.temperature
          }
          snapshot.ref.update(updates).then(() => {
            res.send(current);
          }).catch(error => {
              console.error('Update failed:', error);
              res.send('Update failed'); // or some error status of your choice
          });
        });
      }
      else {
        res.send(current);
      }
  });
});
    function diff_minutes(second_time, first_time) {
      var diff =(second_time - first_time) / (1000 * 60);
      return Math.abs(Math.round(diff));
    }
```